# php require minimum 3 words form validation

Tags: php

I have this php code for form validation :

```
if(($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0) || $title == '' || $tags == '') {
                wp_redirect(home_url('/') . '?posterror=1');
                exit; 
            }
```

This form redirect you to a page error if you didn't upload a file, put a title or a tag. From this code I want to change this: `$tags == ''` to something like this: `$tags != 3` but it doesn't work, to require minimum 3 words = 3  tags.

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve this goal?

Comment: i have a frontend upload and this code redirect you if you didin't put a title, upload a file or put a tag , everything ok until here . but i wanna ask for 3 tags not just one. I just wanna know how can i change this code $tags == '' to ask 3 words .. not just one.

Comment: you need to count the words -- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_word_count.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the words, if they are separated by spaces, use

```
if(($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0) || $title == '' || str_word_count($tags) < 3) {
    wp_redirect(home_url('/') . '?posterror=1');
    exit; 
}
```

if they are separated by comma-space `,`, use this

```
if(($_FILES['file']['error'] != 0) || $title == '' || count(explode(", ", $tags)) < 3) {
    wp_redirect(home_url('/') . '?posterror=1');
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: You can accept an answer in 33 seconds . Of course :D